# Vue3 and jsdoc-vuejs empty documentation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, jsdoc

I'm trying to generate the documentation using jsdoc-vuejs. Unfortunately, despite many attempts, I am not able to generate documentation for an example component - the documentation is empty:

[image]

I am using Vue3 and jsdoc-vuejs 4. Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "docs": "rm -rf docs* && jsdoc -d docs -c .jsdoc.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-4",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.9.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "tui-jsdoc-template": "^1.2.2",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.5",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.1.7",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-nightwatch": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.20",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "chromedriver": "91",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "geckodriver": "^1.20.0",
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.7",
    "jsdoc-vuejs": "^4.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0",
    "vue-loader": "^16.8.1",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}
```

My .jsdoc.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        "node_modules/jsdoc-vuejs"
    ],
    source: {
      include: [
        'src/'
      ],
      includePattern: '\\.(vue|js)$'
    },
    opts: {
      encoding: 'utf8',
      destination: 'docs-tui',
      template: './node_modules/tui-jsdoc-template'
    }
};
```

My example component for which I want to generate documentation:

```
<script>
/**
 * Its my component
 * @component
 * @vue-prop {String} msg - Initial counter's value
 */
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In `.jsdoc.js` you need to specify the source path of your components or where vue file that you want to generate the documentation.

```
include: [
  'src/',
  'src/components/',
  'src/views/'
],
```